# TypeScript, AMD and referencing imported classes directly

Tags: typescript, amd

I call my TSC compiler with "--module amd" parameter.

Let's say I have a file geom.ts that contains

```
export class Cube { //implementation }
```

If want to reference the Cube class I do

```
import geom = require('geom');

var myCuble : geom.Cube;
```

In ActionScript I was used to reference the imported classes directly - there would be no "geom." before the "Cube", unless there would be a conflict between multiple imports and I needed to state the whole package path. This module-dot-class convention is annoying, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TypeScript 1.5 onwards, you can use the ES6 style import statements:

```
import { Cube } from 'geom';

var myCube: Cube;
```

This will be compiled to older versions of ECMAScript (if you aren't targeting ES6) by transforming the code into:

```
var glob_1 = require('glob');
var x = new glob_1.Example();
```